# How to get user data from template in Django?

Tags: django

It's probably super simple but I found nothing on this specific case. It doesn't help that I messed up a bit and lost track of what does what.

I want my template to display user account balance.

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Uzytkownik(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    saldo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    adres = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def get_balance(self, request):
        current_user = request.user
        return current_user.saldo
```

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Uzytkownik, User

def index(request):
    context = {'saldo': Uzytkownik.get_balance}
    return render(request, 'bpanelapp/index.html', context)
```

In my template, I refer to it using `<h2>{{context}}</h2>`. Yet the `<h2>` is empty, even though my currently logged in account's `balance` field contains data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to *call* the `get_balance` function:

```
def index(request):
    context = {'saldo': Uzytkownik.get_balance(request)}
    return render(request, 'bpanelapp/index.html', context)
```

Your function itself furthermore will not work: here it requires a `self`. You need to make this a `@staticmethod`:

```
class Uzytkownik(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    saldo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    adres = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_balance(request):
        try:
            return request.user.uzytkownik.saldo
        except Uzytkownik.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

You can not refer to `context`. The context variable does not exists, you passed one value to your template (together with some values you pass implicitly like `request`, and some that are passed through *context processors*).

You thus render this with:

```
<h2>{{ saldo }}</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. It actually was `{{ saldo }}` at one point, but I tried so many different solutions I just got lost.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `{{ saldo }}` in your template rather than `{{ context }}` (which doesn't exist). In addition, you need to be passing `request` into the `get_balance` method, as it is a required argument.